# Is there any way to run Protractor e2e testing automatically?

Tags: protractor

I was working on an angular project and doing some e2e testing with Protractor. But its really annoying to run the

```
ng e2e
```

every time to check whether my testing is working or not. Is there any way that Protractor will check my e2e code and do the testing for me automatically? I really do not want to run the ng e2e which compile the whole project and takes a bit time.

Comment: Are you using any versioning system ? Most of them offer nice tools for testing every time you push a set of changes into the codebase.

Comment: ya, I am using git. how come they run protractor automatically?

Comment: So I don't know any tool for git but there are a few for Github. Tests can be hooked up on the Github API. For my projects I usually use `Travis` => https://travis-ci.org/
Travis can be configured to hook up every commit or Pull Request and then automatically runs tests. 
I recommend migrating from git to Github anyways since they offer a graphical UI.
Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `karma.conf`, there is a property `autoWatch: true` which will run your tests anytime you make any change in the code. [Sample config file](https://gist.github.com/fatihacet/c54b6b3e542aea11da86).

Answer (score 0):

Yes '***WE CAN DO***'. Here is what I do all the time:

From one command window

```
 ng serve
```

And from another command window

```
ng e2e -s false
```

Comment: its not working. protractor cant find the -s flag @twinckletwinckle